# Mustache and nested templates

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a tree-like setup, where each node contains its own Mustache template that might be wrapped in a parent node's template.

```
var templates = {
    secondTmpl: Mustache.compile("<i>Yet another template.. Here's some text: {{text}}</i>     {{date}}"),
    template: Mustache.compile("<b>{{val}}</b><p>{{{outlet}}}</p><ul>{{#list}}<li>{{.}}            </li>{{/list}}</ul> {{test}}")
};

var tree = [
    {
        template: "template",
        data: { val: "yup!!", list: [1,2,3,4,5], test: function() { return new Date(); } },
        children: [
            {
                view: "Main",
                template: "secondTmpl",
                data: { text: "Some Value", date: function() { return new Date(); } }
            }
        ] 
    }
];

function MainView(options) {
    this.template = options.template;
    this.data = options.data;
    this.childViews = options.childViews;
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
}

MainView.prototype.render = function() {
    View.prototype.render.call(this);
    this.postRender();
    return this;
};

MainView.prototype.postRender = function() {
    this.el.getElementsByTagName("i")[0].style.border = "1px dotted red";
};

function View(options) {
    this.template = options.template;
    this.data = options.data;
    this.childViews = options.childViews;
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
}

View.prototype.render = function(renderChildren) {
    if(this.childViews) {
        this.data.outlet = "<div class=\"outlet\"></div>";
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.data);

    if(this.childViews) {
        this.childViews.forEach(function(view) {
            this.el.getElementsByClassName("outlet")[0].appendChild(view.render().el);
        }, this);
    }

    return this;
};

function traverse(node) {
    var viewOptions = {
        template: templates[node.template],
        data: node.data
    };

    if(node.children) {
        viewOptions.childViews = node.children.map(function(n) {
            return traverse(n);
        });
    }

    return node.view ? new window[node.view + "View"](viewOptions) : new View(viewOptions);
}

function init() {
    tree.forEach(function(node) {
        var view = traverse(node);
        document.body.appendChild(view.render().el);
    });
}

window.onload = init;​
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b4fTB/

The reason that I have the data in a tree is because the nested templates varies depending on the users data, and because many templates may be wrapped in different templates.

I don't know if what I'm doing here is stupid, but it allows me to render the templates from C# as well, which is quite nice.

So - the question (comments to the above is of course welcome). When dealing with a template with nested templates, it would be nice to have a simple function that only returns dom elements related to the actual template - and not dom elements from the nested templates. Is this even possible? And is it possible in a way that allows for deeply nested templates and not lose a great deal of performance? In other words, I have two templates where one of them is nested within the other in the jsfiddle. It would be nice not having to worry about nested views in the parent view when dealing with the dom.

Comment: I edited in the code from jsFiddle. Sometimes fiddle links go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I've found a way myself.

Following code requires [mustachejs](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) and [composejs](https://github.com/kriszyp/compose):

```
var noop = function() {};

var templates = {
    secondTmpl: Mustache.compile("<i>Yet another template..  {{{outlet}}}Here's some text: {{text}}</i> {{date}}"),
    template: Mustache.compile("<b>{{val}}</b><p>{{{outlet}}}</p><ul>{{#list}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/list}}</ul> {{test}}")
};

var tree = [
    {
        view: "Main",
        template: "template",
        data: { val: "yup!!", list: [1, 2, 3, "Four", 5], test: function() { return new Date(); } },
        children: [
            {
                template: "secondTmpl",
                data: { text: "Some Value", date: function() { return new Date(); } }
            },
            {
                view: "Test",
                template: "secondTmpl",
                data: { text: "ANOTHER TEMPLATE", date: function() { return new Date(); } },
                children: [
                    {
                        template: "template",
                        data: { val: "Pretty nested template", list: [56, 52, 233, "afsdf", 785], test: "no datetime here" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] 
    }
];

var View = Compose(function(options) {
    Compose.call(this, options);
    this.el = document.createElement(this.tag);
}, {
    tag: "div",
    render: function() {
        if(this.childViews) {
            this.data.outlet = "<div class=\"outlet\"></div>";
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.data);

        this.didRender();

        if(this.childViews) {
            var lastEl;

            this.childViews.forEach(function(view) {
                if(!lastEl) {
                    var outlet = this.el.getElementsByClassName("outlet")[0];
                    lastEl = view.render().el;
                    outlet.parentNode.replaceChild(lastEl, outlet);
                } else {
                    var el = view.render().el;
                    lastEl.parentNode.insertBefore(el, lastEl.nextSibling);
                    lastEl = el;
                }
            }, this);
        }

        this.didRenderDescendants();

        return this;
    },
    didRender: noop,
    didRenderDescendants: noop
});

var TestView = View.extend({
    didRender: function() {
        var nodes = this.el.querySelectorAll("*");
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length;i++)
            nodes[i].style.border = "2px dotted red";
    }
});

var MainView = View.extend({
    didRender: function() {
        var nodes = this.el.querySelectorAll("*");
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length;i++)
            nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
});

function traverse(node) {
    var viewOptions = {
        template: templates[node.template],
        data: node.data
    };

    if(node.children) {
        viewOptions.childViews = node.children.map(function(n) {
            return traverse(n);
        });
    }

    return node.view ? new window[node.view + "View"](viewOptions) : new View(viewOptions);
}

function init() {
    tree.forEach(function(node) {
        var view = traverse(node);
        window["view"] = view;
        document.body.appendChild(view.render().el);
    });
}

window.onload = init;
```

The trick is to replace the div.outlet with the first child view instead of appending to it. Then it's a matter of inserting the other child views next to each other.